# How to change which page wordpress get_header() loads

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to load a Wordpress page in another php file. Since I have integrated CodeIgniter with Wordpress.

The following works without problems and loads the wordpress site.

```
get_header();
get_footer();
```

But how do I change which page is loaded, instead of the homepage?

I only want to call the get_header() and get_footer wp functions but find a way to select the page.

I have thus far tried altering the $wp_query global object but haven't had any success.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The following worked:

```
$page_to_load = new WP_Query(array(
    'page_id' => $page_id
));

global $wp_query;
$wp_query = $page_to_load;
wp();
get_header();
get_footer();
```

This sets the page to load in the $wp_query object, and then you have to call wp() in order to reload the page and have it route to the page.

Comment: I just have to add that this works perfectly fine with the Pagelines DMS.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display the header and footer only on some pages. There are 2 functions, which should solve the problem.

First one:
[is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

This one just tests, whether the displayed page is your front page. You just need to use it like this:

```
<?php
echo is_front_page() ? "I'm a front page." : "This isn't a front page"
?>
```

Second one: [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

There are multiple ways to use this function. First one (without any parameter) just tests, whether it is page. Second one (with an ID) only returns true, if the requested page has got the specific ID. Third one (with slug or post title) is the same like the second only with those parameters.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need. I am using get_header() and get_footer() in different files, and on each of those files I want to render a different page.